# UITableView delegate and datasource in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, delegates

I have a UITableView inside a UITableViewCell and I need to figure out how to set the sub table view datasource and delegate. At the moment this is what I have:

**MainTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>


@end
```

**MainTableViewController.m**

```
#import "MainTableViewController.h"
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@interface MainTableViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation MainTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UITableView delegate functions

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"tableViewCell";
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    cell.cellLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}


@end
```

**TableViewCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *subTableView;

@end
```

**TableViewCell.m**

```
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@implementation TableViewCell

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.subTableView.delegate = self;
        self.subTableView.dataSource = self;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"subTabeViewCell"];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"subTabeViewCell"];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"test";

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Because I can't ctrl + drag from my sub table view to the TableViewCell class, I'm trying to set the delegate and datasource programmatically within the initialisation, but it's not working and I'm just getting straight up confused.

I know I can set the datasource and delegate to connect to the first class and then within each of the delegate functions check to see which tableView I'm dealing with, but the with the nature of what I'm trying to do it won't really work, I've tried.

So all help is welcome

Comment: The designated initialiser for a UITableViewCell is initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier - try setting the datasource and delegate in this method

Comment: @Paulw11initWIthStyle is only called when you are creating the tableViewCell programmatically, I'm creating it within the IB, so initWithStyle isn't called, initWithCoder is

Comment: Then what you have should work. Have you set breakpoint so to verify what is happening?

Comment: Yep, it looks like it's all working, but when I set the cell.textLabel.text in the cellForRowAtIndexPath it doesn't work, they're just blank cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out, well i figured out a way of doing it. Within the cellForRowAtIndexPath in the MainTableViewController.m, I simply added:

```
[cell.subTableView setDelegate:cell];
[cell.subTableView setDatasource:cell];
```

And all is working away